# Update SharedWith using Sharepoint 2013 API

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am trying to update specific property of Sharepoint 2013 list item, ie. 'SharedWithUsersId'. Although I get the response code as 204 (indicating success), when I check the list item again, I am not seeing any change in the sharedWithUSersId. When I tried changing other properties, like title, it worked like a charm. So, I want to know if 'sharedWithUSersId' property cannot be edited via this particular api call?

Cheers, Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be changed, but not directly. You can do it by REST API. For example:

```
function setNewPermissionsForGroup() {
var endpointUri = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('";
endpointUri += listTitle + "')/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=" + groupId;
endpointUri += ",roledefid=" + targetRoleDefinitionId + ")?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";

executor.executeAsync({
    url: endpointUri,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'X-RequestDigest':$('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val() },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495392(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Can't I do it on per user basis instead of group ? Furthermore, is it possible to do the same per item basis instead of per list? Basically I want as granular control as possible